Android RTSP Stream with MJPG Format: no data received in 10s, aborting
I am using libvlc to access an RTSP Stream (MJPEG format) from a network camera in a local network (rtsp://192.168.0.51:8554/MCDE3000).
The below code works fine for Internet RTSP Streams (H.264 Format).
My Kotlin code:
class VLCStreamActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var vlcVideoLayout: VLCVideoLayout
    private var libVLC: LibVLC? = null
    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vlcstream)

        // Initialize VLCVideoLayout
        vlcVideoLayout = findViewById(R.id.vlc_video_layout)

        // Initialize LibVLC
        val options = arrayListOf(
            "-vv", // Enable verbose logging
            "--rtsp-frame-buffer-size=2000", // Adjust buffer size if necessary
            "--network-caching=1500"
        )
        libVLC = LibVLC(this, options)

        // Initialize MediaPlayer
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer(libVLC).apply {
            attachViews(
                vlcVideoLayout,
                null,
                false,
                false
            )
        }

        // Play RTSP Stream
        val media = Media(libVLC, Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.0.51:8554/MCDE3000")).apply {
            setHWDecoderEnabled(true, false) // Enable hardware decoding
            addOption(":network-caching=3000") // Increase network caching to 3 seconds
            addOption(":rtsp-tcp") // Force RTSP over TCP
            addOption(":rtsp-timeout=60") // Extend the RTSP timeout to 60 seconds
            addOption(":live-caching=3000") // Additional caching for live streams
            addOption(":rtsp-frame-buffer-size=5000") // Increase buffer size
            addOption(":demux=mjpeg") // Specify MJPEG as the demuxer

        }
        mediaPlayer?.media = media
        media.release()

        try {
            mediaPlayer?.play()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("RTSPStreamActivity", "Error playing RTSP stream", e)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to play the stream.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

Of course, INTERNET permission was enabled and the IP address was added in network_security_config.xml.
The log shows that the camera is successfully connected: input: rtsp://192.168.0.51:8554/MCDE3000' successfully opened
However, after 10 seconds, I received the error message: libvlc access: no data received in 10s, aborting
Full log:
2024-12-05 10:10:34.574 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b40000748e7e4890/66e0] libvlc access: play start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
2024-12-05 10:10:34.574 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [00000073cf553790/66e0] libvlc generic: using access module "live555"
2024-12-05 10:10:34.574 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [00000073cf5532e0/66e0] libvlc generic: looking for video decoder module matching "any": 15 candidates
2024-12-05 10:10:34.574 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b4000074ee7f4280/66e0] libvlc decoder: using ffmpeg Lavc60.31.102
2024-12-05 10:10:34.574 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b4000074ee7f4280/66e0] libvlc decoder: CPU flags: 0x00000160
2024-12-05 10:10:34.575 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b4000074ee7f4280/66e0] libvlc decoder: allowing 5 thread(s) for decoding
2024-12-05 10:10:34.575 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b4000074ee7f4280/66e0] libvlc decoder: codec (mjpeg) started
2024-12-05 10:10:34.575 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [00000073cf5532e0/66e0] libvlc generic: using video decoder module "avcodec"
2024-12-05 10:10:34.575 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b40000751e7ebcf0/66e0] libvlc input: ES track selected: 'video/auto/0' (fourcc: 'MJPG')
2024-12-05 10:10:34.575 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [00000073cf5539b0/66e0] libvlc generic: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
2024-12-05 10:10:34.575 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b40000741e7ff380/66e0] libvlc demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/com.example.androidwatchapp/app_vlc/.share/lua/meta/reader
2024-12-05 10:10:34.575 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [00000073cf5539b0/66e0] libvlc generic: no meta reader modules matched with name any
2024-12-05 10:10:34.575 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b40000751e7ebcf0/66e0] libvlc input: `rtsp://192.168.0.51:8554/MCDE3000' successfully opened
2024-12-05 10:10:45.113 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          E  [b40000748e7e4890/66e0] libvlc access: no data received in 10s, aborting
2024-12-05 10:10:45.113 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b40000751e7ebcf0/66e0] libvlc input: EOF reached
2024-12-05 10:10:45.113 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b4000074ee7f4280/66e0] libvlc decoder: killing decoder fourcc `MJPG'
2024-12-05 10:10:45.113 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b4000074ee7f4280/66e0] libvlc decoder: removing "video decoder" module "avcodec"
2024-12-05 10:10:45.114 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b40000751e7ebcf0/66e0] libvlc input: ES track unselected: 'video/auto/0' (fourcc: 'MJPG')
2024-12-05 10:10:45.114 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b40000748e7e4890/66e0] libvlc access: removing "access" module "live555"
2024-12-05 10:10:45.114 26275-26327 VLC-std                 com.example.androidwatchapp          E  Sending request: TEARDOWN rtsp://192.168.0.51:8554/MCDE3000/ RTSP/1.0
                                                                                                    CSeq: 6
                                                                                                    User-Agent: LibVLC/4.0.0-dev (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2022.07.14)
                                                                                                    Session: -67682726
2024-12-05 10:10:45.114 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b40000751e7ebcf0/66e0] libvlc input: ES track deleted: 'video/auto/0' (fourcc: 'MJPG')
2024-12-05 10:10:45.114 26275-26336 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b40000751e7ebcf0/66e0] libvlc input: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
2024-12-05 10:10:45.114 26275-26333 VLC                     com.example.androidwatchapp          D  [b40000751e7ebcf0/66dd] libvlc input: destroying input for 'rtsp://192.168.0.51:8554/MCDE3000'


You know that mjpeg is very high bandwith or ? based on resolution/compression and fps could up to 100Mbit so are you sure its not a bandwith issue. did you Change the Code in the camera to mjpeg?

The code in the camera is mjpeg by default, I did not change it. The VLC Android app manages to stream the RTSP stream without issues, and since I use the libvlc library, I assumed it would work accordingly..

Use libvlc stable, that is version 3

I also tried it with the dependency "org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3.5.1". Still aborting after 10s (connection can be established). Am I missing other dependencies or settings?
